North Africa, World War II, a group of commandos, and a scorpion
The movie is set in World-War II where some commandos are sent to North Africa to assassinate a high-ranking person.
In one of the scenes, it's night, and a black scorpion is walking towards a wounded soldier. Another soldier wants to kill the scorpion, but the commander won't let him. At last scorpion stings the wounded soldier and kills him. 
The commander says, "He was a burden for us".
Which movie is this?
Update: I vaguely remember that at the last of the movie, commandos open a door to shoot a general, but some soldiers are ready and as soon as the door gets opened, they shoot back the commandos. I think commandos think that the voice of the general is coming from behind the door, but it turns out that the voice is coming from radio.

Any more informations that might help identify it? When did you watch it/what time was it likely from? From what country was it likely? Were that German or British soldiers?

Nothing more comes to my mind. I saw this movie like 10 years ago. I'm sorry.
